# Why is collection initialized with proxies in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, collections, many-to-many

I have very simple @ManyToMany relationship between User and Topic:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<Topic> getTopics() {
    return topics;
}
```

When I traverse this collection by Iterator every element returned is proxy of Topic entity.
Its class name is : Topic_javassist_4.
But As I know collection should be initialzed with elements of concrete type ('Topic' in my case). 
Why is collection 'topics' filled with proxies ?

**UPDATE** This seems impossible but it is! Already in active transaction I traverse through my 'topics' collection and print class name of every Topic entity:

```
package_name.Topic_$$_javassist_4
package_name.Topic
```

**Why in the same collection first topic is not initialized and second one is?**

BTW, hibernate logs select statements to select my Topic entities and values are printed to console, they are all correct values of my both topics from collection

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your relation to Topic as LAZY. This means that, whenever a User is fetched, it's associated topics are not fetched unless really necessary. Proxies are the mechanism to achieve this.

Are you traversing your collection from within a transactional boundary, or is the transaction already closed at the moment you iterate over your Topics? It seems that you have loaded your Users, closed the connection, and then started iterating over your Topics?

Comment: Thaks for response! You are completely right, I loaded user inside transaction, then I closed session then I iterate over 'topics'.

Comment: I need to initialize collection inside transaction! Thanks again!

Comment: Collection really had one initialize and one not initialized Topic. I initialized evry Topic entity by : if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
   entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
  }